# Cannot Resolve Assembly Microsoft.Expression.Interactions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression, mvvm-light

I'm currently trying to implement a plugin system found [here](http://www.alphablog.org/2012/05/07/simple-plugin-system-based-on-ninject-and-mvvm-light-2/). It's a wonderful plugin system but If I try to load the designer for the MainWindow.xaml on the included WpfApplication I get an exception:

```
System.Reflection.Adds.UnresolvedAssemblyException
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Microsoft.Expression.Interactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
```

Everything builds and runs fine but it's particularly frustrating to design in XAML without a UI view. Is there any way around this error? What's actually happening here?

Also the .dll is located in my projects folder under "C:...\PluginSystem\Libraries\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll". The .dll is distributed with the plugin System itself.

The opening window tag:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PluginSystem.Controls;assembly=PluginSystem" 
xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects" 
xmlns:PluginSystem="clr-namespace:PluginSystem;assembly=PluginSystem" 
xmlns:PluginSystem_Controls="clr-namespace:PluginSystem.Controls;assembly=PluginSystem" 
xmlns:Plugin1="clr-namespace:Plugin1;assembly=Plugin1" 
xmlns:Plugin3Dependency="clr-namespace:Plugin3Dependency;assembly=Plugin3Dependency" 
xmlns:WpfApplication_ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.ViewModel" 
x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" mc:Ignorable="d" Width="525">
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin system but make sure it's not blocked, since you downloaded it off the web. (Right click on the DLL...Properties...and Click `Unblock` if the option is there).

Comment: I unblocked the original .zip file. All files are unblocked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are adding a reference in your Project to the DLL and properly including the Namespace in your MainWindow.

Comment: I've tried removing and adding the references, adding usings to MainWindow, and even using references directly to the Blend SDK I have installed on my machine. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: I made an edit to my question. Hopefully the provided information will be useful.

Comment: Are you sure that you added all necessary files (not references) to your project in Visual Studio?

Comment: I can't know that for sure yet. I'd imagine I have all files as I'm able to compile the application and run it without error. I can post the entire MainWindow.Xaml here if you'd like to see it.

Comment: What .NET version is your project?

Comment: I'm currently using 4.0.